# This is not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When trying to execute an SQL Query on an ORACLE Database I get this error :

> "This is not a valid month"

Here is the expression:

```
TO_DATE(trim(my_char_column), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM soc1.tie tiers WHERE TRIM(codzn6) NOT LIKE 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'` Then correct your data and start storing dates as DATE datatype.

Comment: Can you give us data example for your `tiers.codzn6`?

Comment: Thx Lukasz, you're right. It Seems that some datas are in the 'DDMMYYYY' format